# VMWare machine - computer security and privacy?

Tags: security, virtual-machine, vmware, data-access, anonymity

I'm running a virtual machine on my computer (a Win XP machine in VMWare Player 5.0.1).
My computer, and my network, contain very sensitive data I do not which to expose to the XP machine.

Can I be confident that there is virtually **no** way for applications inside my virtual XP accessing data (such as files) from my physical computer, or any shared network resources?

If not, how can it be prevented?
I noticed that my virtual XP cannot access the network at least (like ping any computer, or see shared network folders).

So basically my questions is **How "secure" is my virtual machine?**

What information can be gathered about, or from, the host and its environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't worry about data security of the physical machine. The VMware player deployed Xp machine user can not able to access the files in the physical machines. Unless the physical machine drives are manually OS mounted inside the virtual machine. Though the VM is running inside the physical machine as application it will act as a separate OS.